# Some questions about well condition of a problem

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Considerer the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and the system $Ax=b$ with $b=(1,1)$ find an upper bound of $||\delta_x||_\infty/||x||_\infty$ in terms of $||\delta_b||_\infty/||b||_\infty$, with $\delta_b=(\delta_1,\delta_2)$, is the problem well or badly conditioned?

$A= \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & \epsilon\\0 &1\end{array}\right]$ with $\epsilon \geq 0$

So for the first part I know

$||\delta_x||_\infty/||x||_\infty\leq K(A)\cdot $ $||\delta_b||_\infty/||b||_\infty$

If we calculate
$K(A)=||A||_\infty\cdot||A^{-1}||_\infty = (1+\epsilon)^2$ , $||b||_\infty =1$ and $||\delta_b||_\infty = \max(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ in fact

$||\delta_x||_\infty/||x||_\infty\leq (1+\epsilon)^2  $ $\max(\delta_1,\delta_2)$

and this problem is well-conditioned if $K(A)$ is near to $1$ in this case if $\epsilon$ is smaller the problem is well-conditioned in other cases is badly-conditioned.

I try to solve in this form but my questions are why the matrix doesn't have perturbation? Is my analysis of well or bad conditioning right?

Answer (score 1):

From the characteristic equation $(1-\lambda)^2=0$ you get: $\lambda_{\min}=\lambda_{\max}=1\implies\kappa(A)=1$ i.e. that the matrix $A$ is well conditioned.

On the other hand, from the analytical solution
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{array}\right]=
\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -\varepsilon \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]}_{A^{-1}}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
b_1 \\ b_2
\end{array}\right],
\end{align}
you also get that the matrix $A$ is well conditioned:
\begin{align}
x=A^{-1}b~\implies~\delta x=A^{-1}\delta b~\implies~||\delta x||_{\infty}\le||A^{-1}||_{\infty}||\delta b||_{\infty}=(1+\varepsilon)||\delta b||_{\infty}.
\end{align}
You do not variate the matrix, because you consider, that it is constant.